# What is the relation between %UTIL VS %WA in sar?

Tags: sar

What is the relation between `%UTIL` VS `%WA` in sar ?

%util

Percentage of CPU time during which I/O requests were issued to the device (bandwidth utilization for the device). Device saturation occurs when this value is close to 100%.

%iowait (in Sar)

Comment: Add some more context, e.g. some example output ?